# How to select text in android Webview and pass the selected text to a string

Tags: android

Im building an app using a Webview. i want to get the selected text in my Webview such that i can manipulate the selected text, like i want the selected text to be highlighted. So far im using the emulateshifheld() but it doesn't solve my problem. It automatically copy text to the clipboard. Using a button to copy the selected text in the Webview could be useful to me.

Does anyone got this idea?

Thank you..,

Answer (score 0):

You can communicate with a `WebView` using `Javascript`. Check this example:

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/using-webviews.html

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. This is what im into but i cannot get the selected text using javascript in adroid.